# Going back to a main screen after running a particular function in python

Tags: python, networking

So I have a program that has a main menu of sorts and you select an option and then it runs a function based off of number selected.

What I'd like to do is after the user runs an option for them to come back to the main menu if they'd like. Here is an example of what it looks like:

```
from module import submodule

def function1(x):
  do something
  return something

def function2(y):
  do something
  return something

def function3(z):
  do something
  return something

print "Welcome to this script. Please choose an option:\n"
print "\t [1] Do something crazy.\n"
print "\t [2] Do something crazier.\n"
print "\t [3] Do something insane.\n"

x = 0

while x == 0:
  r = raw_input("Type in your number to select an option.")
  if r == "1":
    x = raw_input()
    function1(x)
    x = 1
  elif r == "2":
    y = raw_input()
      function2(y)
      x = 1
  elif r == "3":
    z = raw_input()
      function3(z)
      x = 1
  else:
    print "That is not a valid option. Please try again.\n"
```

As you can see, once one of the function runs, it's done. I'd like it to where I can give the user an option to go back to the main menu if they want.

Comment: Wrap it in another while loop that checks whether the user wants to go back.

Comment: That will do it! Thanks!